# Excel fails to throw errors on Workbooks.Open or Workbook.Save methods on files that are in use

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio

Our code essentially does the following:

1) It creates an Excel.Application object, and invokes .Workbooks.Open to open a file from a network location
2) It makes a minor change to the open Workbook
3) It invokes the .Save() method to save the workbook

This is causing a problem when the file is currently in use because
1) NO error is raised on .Workbooks.Open - The workbook simply gets opened in ReadOnly mode, but no messages or nothin' are shown to the user. So unless the user pays close attention and looks at the Title Bar, he or she will have NO idea that the document has actually been opened in ReadOnly mode

BUT the worst thing is

2) The .Save() method on the WorkBook object raises NO error WHATSOEVER. Instead it just goes ahead and saves the document to the %UserProfile%\Documents folder. Not only does it raise no error that WE can catch in code, it shows no message or warning to the USER either, so they remain blissfully unaware of the fact that they are no longer working on the original document in the Network Location, but on a local copy of same instead.

So the questions are:

1) Can we either force Excel to show a message to the END USER *or* raise an error on the .Workbooks.Open method so we can handle it in code? At the moment all I can do is check the workbook's .ReadOnly property, but that will give me no clue as to whether the workbook is ACTUALLY Read Only, or whether it was open in Read Only mode because it is in use by another user, let alone tell us in code, or the user through a message box, by WHOM the workbook might be in use.

2) Can we force Excel to raise an error or prompt the user on the workbook's .Save method, rather than simply saving it somewhere local without any indication to anyone!?!?

Sorry if I sound exasperated.... you should have heard the customer....

```
'Please note that oXApp is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application that has been instantiated correctly.

Dim oWBS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
Dim oWBK As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing

oWBS = oXApp.Workbooks

oWBK = oWBS.Open(sFile) 'No error raised here, nothing. Document is opened in ReadOnly mode. sFile contains a UNC path to a file that is in use by another user.

oWBK.Save() 'Again, no error raised, but while oWBK.FullName points at the UNC path BEFORE the Save, it now refers to a local path in %UserProfile%\Documents
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the customer is correct, or the customer should learn Excel. The warning is pretty hard to ignore - it's not only the *Title*, there's a warning underneath the title. There's even a warning that someone else has already opened the file for editing

Comment: You *can't* save a Read-Only spreadsheet either, not even edit it. Which means that you either opened it for *editing* somehow. Opened it as a template perhaps? As for saving, it *doesn't* save files arbitrarily. `Documents` is the default save folder used when a *NEW* file is saved. Did you open that file as a *template* perhaps?

Comment: In any case, without any code one can only guess what happened. I'd guess the customer is correct. You opened an existing spreadsheet as a template and saved a *new* file without specifying a path, thus saving it in the default folder for all documents

Comment: No, there definitely isn't a template involved, nor opening a file "as a template".

Comment: sorry - I thought enter would give me a new line. I'll include a code snippet, give me a minute ...

Comment: In the following example, oXApp is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

Dim oWBS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
Dim oWBK As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing

oWBS = oXApp.Workbooks

oWBK = oWBS.Open(sFile)

(I left out all the error handling etc to keep it simple. sFile contains a UNC path to an existing document)

Comment: sorry I can't get the code formatting to work .... Ctrl + K doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: In the following example, oXApp is a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application

`
Dim oWBS As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks = Nothing
Dim oWBK As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook = Nothing

oWBS = oXApp.Workbooks

oWBK = oWBS.Open(sFile)
`
(I left out all the error handling etc to keep it simple. sFile contains a UNC path to an existing document)

Comment: Sorry sorry sorry sorry.... I just CANNOT get the code formatted correctly it's infuriating

Comment: @PinoCarafa, please do not attempt to show code in your comments.  Edit your question to add new information.

Comment: @TnTinMn thanks a million. I thought I was going crazy. Have done so now.

Comment: If you ever need to enter a single line or bit of code in a comment, you can surround it with back ticks. The small ` below the tilde (~) on US keyboards.